# perfomance infinite scroll on pc browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, performance, infinite-scroll

I would use infinite scroll for display in page a potential huge list of results.
For example, if a timeline user in facebook has 400 000 posts how infinite scroll in facebook work for display all posts in pages? If it load on scrolling all posts a browser get down performance or crash?

What is the best method to display huge data in infinite scroll without kill browser performance?

Comment: Is there is a reason you're using infinate scroll (aside from making it look good?) rather than pagination?

Comment: this can be a useful plugin: http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Comment: @Alan Shortis Yes because some posts can be deleted so, if I display one page with pagination method, it can be results that some page are empty because user has deleted posts in that page, so this isn't beautiful design

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX Requests for this. Example:

You display about 20 posts or something like that and if the User gets to the last post you send the ajax request Async and load the next 20 posts.

Comment: and if the list gets bigger then e.g. 400 post delete +/- 200 else it will still get laggy if you loaded 400 000 posts.. and to be complete: if you scroll back up reload the previously deleted..

Comment: Ok, but my problem is that I have 200 000 posts, if load next 20 posts, then 20 post until 200 000 posts, browser window has performance problem. Possible solutions can be display in infinite scroll 4 pages -> 20 * 4 = 80 posts, then user click "more" end I refresh page for loading next posts from 81 on, also in infinite scroll

Comment: ok but isn't that easy to solve by loading the next 100 posts or 200 posts in staid of the next 20?

Comment: yeah, you can also use the refresh/reload of the page and view 100 posts. Then display the next 100 or last 100 posts with a simple link.